# Understanding Module.nesting in Ruby and the types of Module Nestings

Tags: ruby

What I know about Modules: Modules cannot be instantiated, do not create objects, and do not support inheritance. Now I am reading [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) to fully understand the Rails autoload feature. And it introduces a topic on Ruby constants, particularly Modules and Classes.

Class and module definitions can be nested to create namespaces:

```
module XML
  class SAXParser
    Module.nesting.inspect
  end
end

 => "[XML::SAXParser, XML]"
```

Rails Guides states that the nesting at any given place (e.g. Module.nesting shown above) is the collection of enclosing nested class and module objects outwards. I think this means that it expands as it goes outward, so inner would be C::B::A, then next level up would be B::A, and next level up would be A, assuming:

```
module A 
  module B
    class C
    end
  end
end
```

Then another case is given:

```
class XML::SAXParser
  Module.nesting.inspect
end
 => "[XML::SAXParser]"
```

As you can see, the nesting is different. The Rails Guide states "XML does not belong to it". What does this statement mean? Does not belong to it? There is no inheritance in Modules. Can someone better explain the difference between these two cases?

Comment: You may wish to look at [this article](https://blog.honeybadger.io/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/), though @Max provides a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, nesting is a *syntactic* construct. In other words, it has to do with how the code is actually written out in the script. The difference in nesting is obvious if you ignore the *semantics* by removing the names, and just look at the syntax:

```
module ...
  class ...
    ...
  end
end

# as opposed to

class ...
  ...
end
```

One is a class inside a module, the other one is just a class. Semantically, both can refer to the same *object* `XML::SAXParser`, but nesting doesn't care about that.

This matters in Ruby because constant lookup is performed using nesting, as opposed to method lookup which uses the semantic object relationships.

```
A = "top level"
module XML
  A = "module level"
  class SAXParser
    puts A # module level

    def self.a
      "defined in a class in a module"
    end
  end
end

class XML::SAXParser
  puts A # top level
  puts a # defined in a class in a module
end
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "semantic object relationships"?

Comment: I mean things like inheritance, included modules, singleton classes. All of the ways that objects relate to each other in meaning, not just how they're organized in your source code.